# How is the Gregorian week and the Islamic week aligned?

Tags: practical-islam, lunar-calendar

In Arabic dates off the week are numbered 1-7. In English and other similar languages,  they are named after 'gods' and 'goddesses'.

But hoe it's or that the Friday of one week matches the equivalent of the Islamic week? Why are they not misaligned liked the months (albeit with a fixed offset)?

Comment: There is a detailed discussion of it here: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16923/how-come-every-culture-on-the-planet-has-a-different-calendar-yet-follow-the-sa

Comment: JazakAllah alkhairen for that.  I feel it would be sufficient to compare pre- and post- Islamic calendars. If the days of the week are unchanged then it is simply that they did not need to change. If they did InshaAllah wet can know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered elsewhere, in this [history.stackexchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/16925/1288) answer (excerpt):

> In the ancient world there were two forms of the seven-day week. First, the Jewish week (eventually adopted by Christians and Muslims) has numbered days from one (Sunday) to six (Friday) and the Sabbath on the seventh day.

Because the days of the week don't necessarily have to tie up with the days of the year (e.g. Jan 1 is not always a Friday), the days of the week they've stayed in step throughout the ages.